# Add SELECT period on last recording each day

Tags: mysql

I have a program that selects the last recording of each day for a given date. This part of my code works good. But now I would like to add a new feature, namely select a given period. Unfortunately I can't do it. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Code to select the last recording

```
SELECT  t1.Measure, t1.created_at
FROM waterstation.waterstation_lifecycle_history t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS createdAt, MAX(created_at) AS maxcreatedAt
FROM waterstation.waterstation_lifecycle_history
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
) t2
ON t2.createdAt = DATE(t1.created_at) AND
t2.maxcreatedAt = t1.created_at
ORDER BY t1.created_at
```

The result is

[image]

after adding a selected period

```
SELECT 
t1.id, t1.created_at
FROM waterstation.waterstation_lifecycle_history t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS createdAt, MAX(created_at) AS maxcreatedAt
FROM waterstation.waterstation_lifecycle_history
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
 ) t2
ON t2.createdAt = DATE(t1.created_at) AND
t2.maxcreatedAt = t1.created_at
ORDER BY t1.created_at AND
DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE('2022-09-13') AND DATE('2022-09-27')
```

the expected result that I don't have

[image]

Comment: the last additional clause belongs into a WHERE and not to the ORDER BY

Comment: Please do not ask your question in ALL CAPS. It makes text harder to read and understand, and globally it is considered to be SHOUTING on the internet. It's rather impolite to come here and shout at the people you're asking for help. If you look at the questions on the main page of this site, none of them except  yours is IN ALL CAPS.

Comment: What *do* you get with the between query?  Note that 2022-09-27 13:15:12 will not be found.  datetime between date and date converts the dates to date times, so your period ends at 2022-09-37 00:00:00, not the end of that day.  Better to say `created_at >= '2023-09-13' and created_at < '2023-09-28'`

Comment: @nbk thanks, I just change my code as you explained and now it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modified my code like this and now it's work

```
SELECT 
t1.Measure, t1.created_at
FROM waterstation.waterstation_lifecycle_history t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS createdAt, MAX(created_at) AS maxcreatedAt
FROM waterstation.waterstation_lifecycle_history
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
) t2
ON t2.createdAt = DATE(t1.created_at) AND
t2.maxcreatedAt = t1.created_at
-- ORDER BY t1.created_at 
WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE('2022-09-27') AND DATE('2022-10-16')
```